# How to add Function to URL in PHP

Tags: php, function, url

I have code like this

```
function demo() {
    echo 'this is demo';
}
```

i want to add this function to here :

http://domain.com/index.php/demo

it possible ? i see this in Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "add a function to a URL". You can however set some GET variables in the URL and catch those on another page.

You should have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php on how to use them